# How can you monitor for click events in Google Apps script for spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm managing a Google spreadsheet with a script. onEdit is working - I can colour a cell red by putting

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setBackgroundRGB(255, 0, 0);
```

in the onEdit function. I would like to put the same code in a onClick function, so that when a user clicks on a cell it immediately turns red. Is this possible? I can't find any way to do it in the documentation.

Comment: sorry, no click event in an individual cell. You would have to create a button, choose the cell, then click the button.

Comment: Ah, ok. How do you add a button to a cell though? Is that done via scripting or the spreadsheets gui?

Comment: You don't add the button to a cell. You add the button to the sheet using the drawing object and then attach it to a script that tells it to turn the active cell red. Then, you choose whatever cell you want to turn red and click the button which runs the script. Can be done with menu item also if you want to enable across many sheets.

Comment: For inserting a button(drawing) see docs:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_extensions?hl=en#drawings

Answer (score 4):

As stated on the comments above before there's no way (right now) to create an `onClick()` function for Google Spreadsheets. That makes sense due to the fact that the google app script functions are processed in the server, the amount of load generated by `onClick()` events execution would make pretty easy to deplete all the quota of requests provided by default.

You should be using the documentation for [creating a button and clicking on it](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus?hl=en#drawings).

Comment: by the same reasoning a change to any value can create tons of traffic as all formulas need to be updated. there must be a way to allow at least part of the API in the client side and allow attaching to functions that are restricted to use that API (or error if they try to do something else)

Comment: What's the difference between a button with a handler and a cell with a handler?

Answer (score 4):

You can get closer....Create a validation for the cells with an option...like "Done".  Click the dropdown, select Done.  now create a trigger onChange or onEdit to fire.  You can get a cell/range contextualized function....like firing on a row or column.  This is easy to replicate and program for

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Drawing as a button - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets

Answer (score 1):

I believe the new trigger onSelectionChange(e) will achieve this. It's in the docs but at time of writing isn't yet working on my sheet. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers?hl=en

Comment: There's no indication in the docs that `onSelectionChange()` isn't released yet. When you say it isn't working, are you using a script that is bound to the sheet?

Comment: Yes, I've tested in a sheet on which I can trigger onOpen() but onSelectionChange is not firing yet. My comment was based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61408971/what-am-i-doing-wrong-when-using-onselectionchange-for-google-apps-script) but the comment there may be in error.

Comment: That thread got updated to say it's rolled out to everybody. Try again, maybe? Or failing that, try making a fresh document and try in there (in case there's some bug-compatibility mechanism)

Comment: Just to let future readers know, onSelectChange() does work, although you need to do something like this:
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = e.range;
  const selectedValue = range.getValue();
}

Answer (score 1):

Try this for a click event:

function onSelectionChange(e) {
  e.source.toast('Sheet: ' + e.range.getSheet()(.getName() + ' Range: ' + e.range.getA1Notation());
}

Answer (score 0):

Create a "Drawing" with background transparent; then move and place the drawing on top of the cell you need and then assign the script to the drawing.