# Bills sheet scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to create a spreadsheet to create bills. I have previously done this in Excel, and now I want to use Google Sheets, however I am having some problems.

- I tried to create a function to be activated each time that a person clicks a specific range
- I have to save the sheet with a specific name (for example the value of a A1 Row + A2 ROW) and save it into my Google drive account
- I used `importRange()` to import the data of a Google Form, however if I make a copy of the sheet I have to give permission to display the data. (How can I do that but without the permission?)

Answer (score 0):

Each of these is almost a question on it own. However, Here's an answer for your questions:

1) **I tried to create a function that have to be activated each time that a person click a specific range**

Use the onEdit function to perform whatever function you are wishing to perform. However, values will have to be changed in order to perform this function. There's no onClick() fucntion in GAS (As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607673/google-apps-script-sheets-onclick-event-put-an-x-in-cell)). However, Here's a simple example for onEdit:

```
function onEdit()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var actRow = cell.getRow();
  var actCol = cell.getColumn();

//Assuming you want the range to be between rows 5-11 and column 2-9
  if (actRow >= 11 && actRow<=5 && actCol >=2 && actCol<=9)
  {
    //Implement your function
  }
}
```

2) **I have to save the sheet with a specific name ( for example the value of a A1 Row + A2 ROW) and save it into my google drive account**

Here's a simple sample. You will have to modify it according to your use case but this should give you a good idea regarding how to do it:

```
function moveRows(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var sRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, numRows, 1); //Leaving out header rows
  var data = sRange.getValues();

  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('*****');
  var newSpSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Billing Target");
  var newRows = "A"+(1+numRows);
  var newRange = "A2:"+newRows; //Leaving out header rows
  newSpSheet.getRange(newRange).setValues(data);

  //If you need the file to be in a specific folder
  DriveApp.getFileById(newSpSheet.getId()).makeCopy("Billing Target", destFolder);

}
```

3) **I used import range to import the data of a google form however if a make a copy of the sheet y have to give permision to display the data (How can I do that but without the permision)**

As far as I know, You can't do that without a permission.