# Trigger a function on selecting a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-sheets-api

How to write a trigger which gets triggered everytime the user selects any cell. The trigger will call a function which would log the row number of the highlighted cell on Google Apps Scripts

I have already written a function which is doing that:

```
function getCell() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  //get the current highlighted cell
  var cell = sheet.getCurrentCell();

  //get the row number
  var row = cell.getRow(); 

  //log the value
  Logger.log(row);

}
```

But I don't know how to write the trigger. Currently, I have to run the script every time I click on some other cell.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61944971/7215091

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The available triggers are described on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/. An alternative that could serve as a workaround is to use the "poll technique" described on [How do I make a Sidebar display values from cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30628894/1595451)

Answer (score 2):

strange, it worked the first time....

```
function onSelectionChange(e){
   Browser.msgBox('cell selection change');
}
```

maybe things have changed since the question was posted, but landed here.