# What am I doing wrong when using onSelectionChange

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I found this trigger [onSelectionChange(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee) on developers.google.com it should set background to red if a single empty cell is selected. I'm not getting that result with just copy and paste. I don't think I'm missing a step any help would be appreciated.

```
/**
 * The event handler triggered when the selection changes in the spreadsheet.
 * @param {Event} e The onSelectionChange event.
 */
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  // Set background to red if a single empty cell is selected.
  var range = e.range;
  if(range.getNumRows() === 1 
      && range.getNumColumns() === 1 
      && range.getCell(1, 1).getValue() === "") {
    range.setBackground("red");
  }
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. Have you made a bug report?

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE:

It seems it is fully rolled out to all users. You should be able to get it working without any modification to the code. The `e`, event object is similar to the `onEdit` event object.

---

`onSelectionChange` is a recently rolled out feature. Consider waiting a few days for the feature to be rolled out to your specific  project and spreadsheet.

Comment: Is there ETA for this to be available for every script? Also is there going to be https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events updated with event contents exposed?

Comment: @Kos I'm as blind as you are. Usual delay would be a maximum of 2 weeks. Don't know about event objects, but as per demo code, we have at least `e.range`

Comment: Two years later, and they still haven't revealed what is in the e object in the documentation. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events I sent feedback, but I don't know that it will be acted on.

Comment: I added `for (x=0; x<Object.keys(e).length; x++){console.log(Object.keys(e)[x].toString())}` to my `onSelectionChange(e)` function to find that it has the elements `source`, `authMode`, `user`, and `range` . I would assume (but can't be sure without a lot of testing) that these are basically a subset of the elements of `onEdit(e)` without the values and behave the same way - though I wonder if range is before or after the change.

Answer (score 1):

Use the legacy runtime, not the V8 runtime. With V8 runtime in my case sometimes it is triggered, sometimes not. There are general problems with trigger executions in V8, see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147016387

Comment: This issue was reported as fixed.

Comment: I still have problem that sometimes it works, sometimes not.