# handle cell click - Google Spreadsheet - Appscript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is there a way to mimic the `onclick` function using google app script?

I already checked online but could not anything in the official documentation, and the only useful post in StackOverflow is the following: [How can you monitor for click events in Google Apps script for spreadsheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889320/how-can-you-monitor-for-click-events-in-google-apps-script-for-spreadsheets) but it's an old post from 2013.

Does anyone know if anything changed since then?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `mimic the onclick function using google app script`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Some of the answers in that question from 2013 are from 2019-2020 and refer to `onSelectionChange`, which is closest approximation of `onclick` right now.

Comment: Essentially I want to be able to detect when the user clicks on a cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use onSelectionChange trigger:

You can use a simple [onSelectionChange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee) trigger for that.

Just add a function named on `onSelectionChange` and save the project. From now on, every time a different cell is selected, this function will execute.

#### Code sample:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  console.log("A NEW CELL WAS SELECTED!");
  console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

#### Note:

- You might have to refresh the spreadsheet after adding the function, due to [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178615259).
- You can get information on which cell was selected by using the corresponding [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events), an argument that you can add to Apps Script triggers and which contains information about the event. While the properties of this object are not officially documented yet, you can check those by logging `JSON.stringify(e)`, as shown in the sample above.

Comment: Still not officially documented... https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: I added `for (x=0; x<Object.keys(e).length; x++){console.log(Object.keys(e)[x].toString())}` to my `onSelectionChange(e)` function to find that it has the elements `source`, `authMode`, `user`, and `range` . I would assume (but can't be sure without a lot of testing) that these are basically a subset of the elements of 'e' in `onEdit` without the `value`s and behave the same way - though I wonder if range is before or after the change.